# UWP NavigationView header not changing with theme

Tags: uwp, navigationview

When changing the RequestedTheme, the header background of the NavigationView does not update.
Tried to use a headertemplate, but it didn't solve anything.
Same problem with the window titlebar.

before switch:
[image: before switch]

after switch:
[image: after switch]

my code for switching the theme:

```
    public class AppThemeService : IAppThemeService
    {
        public void ApplyTheme(ApplicationTheme? theme)
        {
            var elementTheme = theme.ToElementTheme();
            if (Window.Current.Content is FrameworkElement element)
                element.RequestedTheme = elementTheme;
        }
    }
```

Any know a solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for the navigationview by put the background on it:

```
<NavigationView x:Name="navigationView" Background="{ThemeResource SystemAltHighColor}">
```

Haven't found anything good for the titlebar yet.
Tried fetching the SystemAltHighColor in code from the App.Resources when the theme changes so that I could set it on the titlebar. But that gives me always the same color, black if the app starting in dark mode.